# finding the easy to install vessel sink drain stopper

Tags: drain, sink

I have a vessel sink which is lacking a drain stopper. The vessel sink does not have a pop out system (buttom to pop out the drain). The internal diameter is probably 1 inch. When i look for drain stopper they look like i have to unscrew the pipe from below and then install it. What do i need to buy that is eayy to install without unscrewing the pipe and works well?[image]

Comment: Try shopping for a hair catcher. You may also be able to find a mesh "sink strainer" that will fit the drain from the top, but searching for one online will be a nightmare because the results will all be for basin strainers.

Comment: wow.. thats what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for **rubber drain stopper** or **rubber drain plug** gets plenty of results. For example, [Amazon - Danco](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JFK0GK) has a range of sizes from 7/8" to 1-3/4". I can't vouch for this specific brand, but I have something similar in my tub. The basic idea is rubber will compress a little and if it is sloped a little instead of a cylinder, it can adjust to fit. Measure the drain and pick a stopper that is, ideally, a little larger than the drain at the top and a little narrower than the drain at the bottom.

Comment: I looked at it and it didnt look great. I was looking at things like these: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Drain-Strain-Never-Clog-Universal-Pop-Up-Stopper-in-Chrome-CHR-001/206823614 but not sure whether it works for me

Comment: A pop-up stopper needs a compatible "pop out drain", and you indicated you don't have a button (or presumably a lever or handle) for that. The "universal" in that link means "works on most types of pop out drains", which it does. But if you put it in your sink you won't have an easy way to remove it. The rubber ones (including the one in my tub) have a ring to remove it. The other type (which came with the sink in my laundry room) is a plastic cap. Those don't work as well unless they are EXACTLY the right size. The rubber ones are (literally and figuratively) more flexible.

Comment: doesn't the rubber drain stopper look ugly on a vessel sink?

Comment: It is only in the sink when you need to fill it up with water. The rest of the time it is someplace outside the sink. I would go with white based on your sink - obviously a black stopper would look worse. But no better solution that I know of if the sink isn't designed for a pop-up.

Comment: Okay.. so actually what i need is not a plug. My drain does not have anything at the top. Its literally a hole where if i drop something it will go down the pipes. So i need something on the top to stop that from happening. Not sure if drain stopper is the right term for it